# Adding Structures to Raster DEM using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

[image]

I am trying to simulate Natural flood management in a river catchment, particularly the role of log jams/LWD in the channel. I have created polylines where I want to put my log structures and given them a value field, in meters. I then buffered these polylines and converted them to raster.

What I want to do is add these log jam rasters into the DEM, so they simulate structures in the channel. I have read around the best way to do this and have found two possible methods, but I am unsure if they have worked.

Method 1

- Mosaic to new Raster

  - My issue with this is that the DEM ranges from 5m to 238m, so I am wondering whether the mosaic tool changes a value from, for example 138m, to 1.5m, instead of adding this on. Or am I overthinking it?

Method 2
- Raster calculator using the following equation:
 con(IsNull("New_DEM"),"Existing_DEM",("New_DEM"+"Existing_DEM"))

- This layer now has a very low minimum value, and I am wondering if the same concerns as the Mosaic to new Raster are happening.

Comment: Screenshots of your inputs and outputs would help here, especially a shot of the rasterized logjams, but it sounds like Method 2 is what you want. As far as telling if it worked, zoom to the location of a logjam on your new DEM and see if you can see a "raised" area.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added an image to the original post.

Answer (score 3):

Mosaic operations are for merging adjacent rasters. What you want to do is quite simple:

1. set your dem as the mask and extent raster;
2. add a field with values representing your obstruction height offsets;
3. convert your polygons to a raster;
4. convert the background nodata values to 0;
5. sum the two rasters.